# Javascript: How to account for undefined JSON which breaks for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am having trouble and may be approaching this wrong so open to other solutions. From a fetch call, I am receiving a larger json array of objects which has further nesting in each object. I want to slim down the larger object array to only some values (for each object) and I am currently doing that by iterating over all of the objects in the larger array and taking the values I want from each object and then pushing to a newly created larger array. The below code works sometimes, however there are times where no data is present in some of the values from the json breaking my for loop. For example`data.products[i].images[0].src` in a given object is sometimes undefined, which breaks the loop saying "cant read property .src of undefined" and doesn't iterate all the way through.

**Main questions?**
1. How can I account for undefined values in any given key:value pair without breaking the loop
2. Is there a better way to go about this entirely?

I can edit the answer to include an example of the incoming json if that helps at all

**Edit**
I also want to not include any object which resulted in undefined image in the final array. Is there any way to prevent that object from being added or maybe filter it out later?

```
let productFilter = []

fetch('https://some.json')
    .then(
        function (response) {
            response.json().then(function (data) {

                for (var i = 0; i < data.products.length; i++) {

                    let filteredArray = {

                        "productId": data.products[i].id,
                        "productName": data.products[i].title,
                        "productImg": data.products[i].images[0].src

                    }

                    productFilter.push(filteredArray)

                }

            });
        }
    )
    .catch(function (err) {
        console.log('Fetch Error', err);
    })
```

Comment: basically, what you need to handle is what to do if `data.products[i].images` is an empty array. That will depend on your product requirements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> For `exampledata.products[i].images[0].src` in a given object is sometimes undefined, which breaks the loop saying "cant read property .src of undefined"

The error tells you that `exampledata.products[i].images[0]` is `undefined`, not `exampledata.products[i].images[0].src` itself. To deal with this, you can add a simple if statement inside your for loop:

```
let filteredArray = {
    "productId": data.products[i].id,
    "productName": data.products[i].title,
}

if (exampledata.products[i].images[0]) {
    filteredArray.productImg = exampledata.products[i].images[0].src
}
```

Note that this solution will leave out the `productImg` key when there is no image. Alternatively, you can use Barmar's answer if you want to ensure the key always exists and have an appropriate default, whether it is a default URL or just `undefined`.

**Suggestions:**

1. Use a variable to shorten many lines in your code:

   ```
   product = exampledata.products[i];
   ```

   Now you can do `product.id`, etc.
2. Check out the `map()` function of Array. You can do the same thing you are doing here without writing all of the boilerplate code for the `for` loop.

Answer (score 2):

use a conditional expression:

```
"productImg": data.products[i].images[0] ? data.products[i].images[0].src : "put default image URL here"
```

If you don't want these objects in the array at all, just put a test around the entire code that adds the object.

```
if (data.products[i].images[0]) {
    let filteredArray = {
        "productId": data.products[i].id,
        "productName": data.products[i].title,
        "productImg": data.products[i].images[0].src
    }
    productFilter.push(filteredArray)
}
```

Comment: `undefined` might be appropriate as a value here rather than `""`.

Comment: It might be. My solution assumes they want a more useful default.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice If they didn't know how to handle undefined in the original data, they might have a similar problem dealing with it here.

Comment: Yes, we can only guess what an appropriate default may be here. Alternatively, leaving out the key all together might make sense as in my answer. I think we should be teaching the OP how to handle undefined values when appropriate rather than avoiding them.

Comment: He's probably going to want to display something in that image, so putting the default here is as good as anything.

Comment: yah, I can certainly imagine a situation where the OP has a placeholder image when there isn't one available for the specific product.

Comment: You could use an `if` statement around the code that insert the object.

Comment: I've added that to the answer.

Answer (score -1):

You need to check if data.products[i] exists, otherwise you're attempting to reference properties of an undefined object.  The same logic applies for the lower level reference to images[0].src

```
let productFilter = []


fetch('https://some.json')
    .then(
        function (response) {
            response.json().then(function (data) {

                for (var i = 0; i < data.products.length; i++) {
                  if (data.products[i]) {
                    let filteredArray = {

                        "productId": data.products[i].id,
                        "productName": data.products[i].title,
                       // "productImg": data.products[i].images[0].src

                    }

                    if (data.products[i].images[0]) {
                      filteredArray.productImg = data.products[i].images[0].src;
                    }

                    productFilter.push(filteredArray)
                  } 

                }

            });
        }
    )
    .catch(function (err) {
        console.log('Fetch Error', err);
    })
```